# How to set transparent color in figure in Keynote?

Tags: keynote

In Office 2019 Powerpoint, you can click a figure and define a specific color as transparent. You'd go to `Picture Format` > `Color` > `Set Transparent Color`.

How do I do this in Keynote?

Below is a screenshot from what I do in Powerpoint. I have made the blue transparent.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried selecting the item and clicking the format icon top right?
See image below:

[image]

And using Opacity...

Comment: No, I mean how to set a color from a figure (photo) transparent, not really an object. Say, if my photo has a gray background and I want to set that gray background as transparent

Comment: Not sure I understand? Do you mean to select one color in the photo, such as red and set it as transparent? If you do then you need something like Gimp.

Comment: I'll add one example with figures from Powerpoint. sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: I've added a screenshot, hopefully it will help

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use this:

Click Alpha in the toolbar (or choose Format > Instant Alpha) and then select the color...

Comment: This is better than in office. Thanks